# ANTLR empty block should be documented

Tags: antlr

Anyone know of a way of getting rid of the "empty block should be documented" warning in generated files when using ANTLR. I know I can disable the warning in Eclipse but I would like to keep it enabled and I like having a clean compile.

PathBaseListener.java

```
@Override public void enterPath(@NotNull PathParser.PathContext ctx) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think, you have to insert a command. E.g.:

```
@Override
public void enterPath(@NotNull PathParser.PathContext ctx){
    /* not implemented */
}
```